# Visual block editing: map i

Tags: key-bindings, visual-mode, visual-block

How to map `i` to start editing on visual block mode?

I want the same behavior for `<shift>-i` and `i`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `:h map-expression` to determine which version of visual mode you are in, and change the behaviour accordingly. Visual mode mapping

```
vnoremap <expr> i mode()=~'\cv' ? 'i' : 'I'
```

will make <kbd>i</kbd> act as `i` in visual and linewise-visual modes, and as `I` otherwise, i.e. in blockwise visual mode.

Comment: You can add `<nowait>` (`<expr><nowait>`) to make it quicker (won't wait for a timeout)