# Bind visual mode 'I' and 'A' to always use visual block mode before inserting

Tags: visual-block

Is there a way to bind `I` and `A` in visual mode and visual line mode to switch the selected region to a visual block selection with the same boundaries?

I'd like to be able to use visual line mode to select a group of lines and then use `I` or `A` to add text before or after all of the lines.

For instance, in the following file (with line numbers)

```
  1 a
  2 b
  3 c
  4 d
  5 e
  6 f
  7 g
  8 h
```

The sequence `<esc> gg V G I # <space> <esc>` produces

```
  1 # a
  2 b
  3 c
  4 d
  5 e
  6 f
  7 g
  8 h
```

and I'd like it to produce this, just as visual block would.

```
  1 # a
  2 # b
  3 # c
  4 # d
  5 # e
  6 # f
  7 # g
  8 # h
```

I've tried using the following keybinding to switch to visual block mode right before inserting in every mode except visual block, but it loses the selection region.

```
vnoremap <expr> I   mode()=~?'\cv' ? 'I' : '<c-v>I'
vnoremap <expr> A   mode()=~?'\cv' ? 'A' : '<c-v>A'
```

Comment: check out the plugin https://github.com/kana/vim-niceblock

Comment: Thanks. The plugin has the answer. `"\<C-v>"` is the string that mode `produces`, not `'\cv'` as described here (https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/6118/6420), evidently.

Plugin: https://github.com/kana/vim-niceblock/blob/master/autoload/niceblock.vim#L33-L35

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt was close, but there are two problems I see:

1. I'm sure you already know this, since you mentioned it in your comment, but `mode()` will return `<C-v>` in visual block mode, not `\cv`.
2. Pressing `<C-v>` from visual line mode will always leave the cursor where it is. And `<C-v>I` will not put the text at the beginning of the line, but right before the cursor. Similarly with `<C-v>A`. So you'll want to use either `0` or `$` to make sure your cursor is where you want it.

This should do what you're looking for:

```
vnoremap <expr> I mode()=~? '<C-v>' ? 'I' : '<c-v>0I'
vnoremap <expr> A mode()=~? '<C-v>' ? 'A' : '<c-v>$A'
```